# Targeted my project in Visual 2010 to .Net 4.0 but the system still looks for the dll 'System.Core version 2.0.5.0'

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, dll

My project targets .Net 4.0 Client profile but it crashes as soon as it starts by displaying a file load exception stating that System.Core version= 2.0.5.0 . How can I change that?

Edit: Forgot to add, it's a WPF project.

Comment: Sounds like a Silverlight project?

Comment: Is this a new project, or have you updated it to use v4?

Comment: It has been being developed in 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you included reference to some libraries belonging to .Net 2.0 and they depends on System.Core 2.0. So you need to check every reference's version number included in your project.

Comment: Yes, I have two reference that are 2.0. I am still not past the problem but it is progress. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

This is mainly for future me, who will at some point come back to this question, and none of the current answers will solve your problem (hey future me!)

My issue was a nuget package referencing System.Core 2.0.5.0 so I had no control over the reference.

To get System.Core 2.0.5.0 installed on the machine, which already had .NET 4.0 installed and patched, I installed the [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx).

> To install the Portable Class Library tools on a build machine without installing Visual Studio 2012, download the [Portable Library Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210823), and save the download file (PortableLibraryTools.exe) on your computer. Run the installation program from a Command Prompt window, and include the **/buildmachine** switch on the command line.

Comment: Do you have any more details of how you did this?

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem similar to this that only occurred on windows XP/Server 2003 while Windows 7/Server 2008 and later worked fine.  After a long time of looking I ran into this article:

http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

It suggested downloading the following hotfix

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871

After installing that everything worked fine!  Maybe give that a try and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that System.Core in References targets version 4. Also, make sure Specific Version is false. You could also try to remove the reference to System.Core and then add it again.

Comment: The Problem with that is that the current system.current gives me the right version but on a debug run. It crashes exactly at same point with the same following message

Comment: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)"

Answer (score 1):

Open the references section in solution explorer, delete the System.Core
Right click on the References and add a new one, locate System.Core v4.0 and add that one.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix a similar error by installing Framework 4.0 UPDATE kb2468871

**Direct link**: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556

**Info Link**: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871